# Adjoint operator $f^{-1}$ applied to sheaf of modules

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am reading Hartshorne, chapter 2, section 5, p. 109. Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a morphism of schemes and $\mathscr{F}$ is a sheaf of $\mathscr{O}_X$-modules. How do we interpret the notation $f^{-1}\mathscr{F}$? There are similar objects using this construction, as in $f^{-1}f_*\mathscr{F}$ in Hartshorne, chapter 2, section 1, exercise 1.18.

Comment: This is the inverse image sheaf, it's defined in section II.1 - the penultimate definition before the exercises start.

Comment: @KReiser : Do we have a module isomorphism $\varinjlim_{f(U)\subseteq V} \mathscr{F}(f^{-1}(V))\cong\varinjlim_{f(U)\subseteq V}\mathscr{F}(f^{-1}(V))^+=\mathscr{F}((f^{-1}\circ f)(U))^+$, where the superscript "+" indicates a sheafification as in Hartshorne prop./def. 1.2.,chapter 2, viewing the sheaf through the corresponding union of stalks?